# In Jquery how to unbind an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

When I click on delete and say no in the confirmation box and again when I try to delete another record the previous record id is getting sent to the backend.

I am using bootstrap modal for confirmation following is the code

```
<div class="modal text-xs-left" id="confirmBoxModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel33" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-xs" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <b>Are you sure ?</b>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="icon-cross2"></i> No</button>
            <button id="btnConfirmBoxDelete" type="submit" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="icon-check2"></i> Yes</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Jquery code

```
$(".deleteAgent").click(function (e) {

            var $buttonClicked = $(this);
            var id = $buttonClicked.attr('data-id');

            $('#confirmBoxModal').modal({
                backdrop: 'static',
                keyboard: false
            })
            .one('click', '#btnConfirmBoxDelete', function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                    url: 'url',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: { "ID": id },
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        toastr.success('Agent Deleted Successfully!', null, { "closeButton": true });
                        location.reload();
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Something went Wrong contact Admin.");
                    },
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $('#loadingDiv').show();
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: i tried using it but couldn't make it work so can you guide me with the code

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - You don't need to *unbind* because you're not *binding* - you're already using `.one()`.

Comment: use $(".deleteAgent").off('click').on('click',function (e) {/* Your code*/ });

Also debug by click on 2-3 elements that  $(this) is  referring to the clicked element

Comment: The issue appears to be around `deleteAgent` - which you've not included in your question.  ie the issue isn't with the delete, it's with initiating the delete.

Comment: Show me full code.

Comment: It's not clear why the previous ID would be sent from that code. Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @Shiljo: Sure -- six years ago. Since Nov 2011: http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `one()` can be added multiple times . When you don't use the first one due to canceling... there will be two of them and they will both trigger. [Demo - multiple one() trigger](https://jsfiddle.net/szvv5v94/)

You could simply assign the current `deleteAgent` id to the modal using `data()` and separate the event listeners

```
$(".deleteAgent").click(function(e) {

  var $buttonClicked = $(this);
  var id = $buttonClicked.attr('data-id');

  $('#confirmBoxModal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
  }).data('delete-id', id);

});

$('#btnConfirmBoxDelete').click(function(e) {
  var id = $('#confirmBoxModal').data('delete-id'):
    // make sure id exists before proceeding
    $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: 'url',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: {
        "ID": id
      },
      //.....
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

use it in ajax success

```
$("#btnConfirmBoxDelete").off("click");
```

it will unbind click event

Comment: There's no click event to `off` on `#btnConfirmBoxDelete` click, it's bound with `one`